Cloudflare pages and environments (without branches like development etc)
I am looking to use Cloudflare pages for the deploying of a static web application. Currently we have a staging and a production environment and the application is deployed to S3 and backed by Cloudfront.
However I could remove a lot of this setup and just use cliudflare pages and then also benefit from their preview environments.
I could implement a staging environment by creating a staging branch and then use the main branch for production however I dont really want to change our Git flow.
My thoughts were to have multiple cloudflare pages projects.

Preview environments for anything not on the main branch
Merging to main branch would deploy to github pages using a staging project. E2E's etc can run against this on a staging domain
If tests/checks pass deploy the same built app from main branch to the production cliudflare pages project

Any thoughts on this? Is anyone doing something similar?
